# .NET MAUI - Entrys, Switches in a Grid (Since Preview 15)

Tags: xamarin, grid, .net-maui

Since Preview 15 I can't select Entrys or a Switch in a Grid.
IsEnabled="True" doesn't solve the problem.
Does someone know more?

Comment: You should probably put this in the github issues instead of SO.

Comment: it's already done